# What is wrong with the Ajax code and the PHP radio input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In this code I can not get the radio input value to use for updating the database:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getVote() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  var vote = $('input[name=optionid]:checked').val();
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+vote);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

on the same file the code is:

```
$options = mysql_query ("select * from options where pollid='poll'");
                while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($options))
                {   $id = $row1['id'];
                    $option = $row1['choice'];
                    $votes = $row1['votes'];
                        echo '<form id="poll">';
                        echo '<input type="radio" name="optionid" value="'.$id.'" onclick="getVote()" /><span>'.$option.'</span><br />';
                }

                        echo '</form>';
```

How to get checked radio value to use it on the other page "poll_vote.php"?
By the way options used by the input radio are 3.

Comment: What is `$vote` in this line `xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="$vote);` ?

Comment: `var vote = $('input[name=optionid]:checked').val();
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="$vote);` this is definitely wrong. use `xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote=" + vote);`

Comment: `"poll_vote.php?vote="$vote` -- JavaScript concatenates strings with a `+`, not a `$`.  (I don't know any language which uses a `$` for that...)

Comment: I've made the change as you suggested but it is still not working. I Have a little information about javascript

Comment: mysql_fetch_array function is already remove in php7 so try using PDO, or mysqli

Comment: Are your sure that `$('input[name=optionid]:checked').val();` is what you want ? And not the result of `$('input[name=optionid]').val();` ?

Comment: If you use the "getVote()" on "onclick" inline, you want the value of the current clicked radio, so replace "var vote = $('input[name=optionid]:checked').val();" with "var vote = $(this).attr('value');".

Comment: I need the result $('input[name=optionid]').val(); to use it for querying my table on the poll_vote.php and show the percentage of each option

Comment: @Mido: When you debug this, where/how *specifically* does it fail?  Does the `vote` variable in JavaScript get the value you expect?  Is that value sent in the AJAX request?  What is the server's response?

Comment: @Baro I've tried what you suggested but it is still not working> I need somebody to check the whole code and tell me why it is not working

Comment: First of all, if your "while" make more than one run, you have more than one "form" opened and only one close... this is a first problem ! open your "form pool" before the "while".

Comment: @Baro Thanks for your notice. I did your suggest. What else may be wrong?

Comment: For what I see, trying to imagine your logic at best ... I tried to give you the full answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I do not know if there are other problems , but with these two changes should be tested what happens, and maybe it works.

**Javascript**

```
function getVote() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  var vote = $(this).attr('value');
  alert('your vote: ' + vote); // WITH THIS CHECK IF THE VOTE IS CORRECT
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+vote);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**PHP**

```
$options = mysql_query ("select * from options where pollid='poll'");

echo '<form id="poll">';

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($options))
{   $id = $row1['id'];
    $option = $row1['choice'];
    $votes = $row1['votes'];
    echo '<input type="radio" name="optionid" value="'.$id.'" onclick="getVote()" /><span>'.$option.'</span><br />';
}

echo '</form>';
```

Comment: When I use alert('your vote: ' + vote); he said is undefined and when I used   alert($("input[name=vote]:checked").val()); he showed the correct value i Need for. Is there any way to store this value ($("input[name=vote]:checked").val()) in a var?

Comment: @Mido In this way... "var vote = $("input[name=vote]:checked").val();" But if it works it means that you have edited the PHP version that I have, "[name= vote]" should be "[name=optionid]" in this version. However, if it work...

Answer (score 0):

The problem I notice with the is this line,  `echo '<form id="poll">';`, is repeatedly printed as many as the return number of rows.

In the browser you have,

```
<form id="poll">
  <input type="radio" name="optionid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="getVote()">
<form id="poll">
  <input type="radio" name="optionid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="getVote()">
<form id="poll">
  <input type="radio" name="optionid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="getVote()">
<form id="poll">
  <input type="radio" name="optionid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="getVote()">
<form id="poll">
  <input type="radio" name="optionid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="getVote()">
.
.
.
```

It happens you a number of repeated forms, before this closing tag

```
</form>
```

I offer you arrange your code in this way, for better analysis

```
<?php $options = mysql_query ("select * from options where pollid='poll'"); ?>
<form class="" id="poll" action="" method="post">
<?php while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($options)): ?>
  <?php
    $id     = $row1['id'];
    $option = $row1['choice'];
    $votes  = $row1['votes'];
  ?>
  <input type="radio" name="option<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="getVote()">
  <span><?php echo $option; ?></span>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</form>
```

And will print your form like this,

```
<form id="poll">
  <input type="radio" name="option1" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="getVote()">
  <input type="radio" name="option2" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="getVote()">
  <input type="radio" name="option3" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="getVote()">
  <input type="radio" name="option4" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="getVote()">
</form>
```

notice this part `name="option<?php echo $id; ?>"`? I made it like that so that you can have unique variable for every radio button, and don't forget to make your form like this `<form class="" id="poll" action="" method="post">` so that you sent data via method post.

It may not be the solution, I hope this would help.

Comment: So far every thing is ok. But what change I have to do to the ajax script to match the changes you've made here above? you didn't mentioned nothing

Comment: Nothing really, if everything is okay, that great. your ajax could also applicable in changes, actually nothing I change on the logic, just correcting few errors

Comment: to show the poll bars with their percentage without reloading the page. The ajax code is mentioned here above as well